JakartaEE 10 stateless service and legacy security domain
I made a homework project for BASIC authentication with Wildfly 33 Beta and Elytron.
When I start server include a @Stateless service in the project I get error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEJB0530: The deployment is configured to use a legacy security domain 'servlet-security-quickstart' which is no longer supported.

My jboss-web.xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas
    http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_7_2.xsd">
   <!-- Configure usage of the security domain "other" -->
   <security-domain>servlet-security-quickstart</security-domain>
   <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>

web.xml looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="6.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">

   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>MyDomain admin users</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>ROLE_ADMIN</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <!-- Configure login to be HTTP Basic -->
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>


If I remove the stateless service everything works fine. The Basic auth window displayed and I can login. But when I put JakartaEE components I can't use it. When I remove security-domain (servlet-security-quickstart) from jboss-web.xml I can't login.
Please help me.

Do you still have something like @SecurityDomain("CustomSecurityDomain") in a bean or similar?
If I add those (back) i get the same error.

No, I haven't. Is there SecurityDomain annotation in JakartaEE? Only ServletSecurity what I found

As I understand it there should not be, sorry it did not help.

in jboss-ejb3-ext-api i found the SecurityDomain annotation and I put SecurityDomain("servlet-security-quickstart") to my stateless service and sessionscoped bean and I still have the message above.
